# ListActivity with Recursion Android

Tags: android

my problem is the next one:

I want to use a ListActivity with recursion, so that it is called "x" times, and everytime i click in one article on the list, it is re-calling again the same Activity but it is loading different data, cause what I wanna do is to make menu and sub-menus, and the expandableList is not enough for me because there are gonna be n-levels(i will know dinamically.....).

Anyone has an idea how can I implement it??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store every data in some kind of N level ArrayList. Write your Adapter class to accept a level of this list. On the item click, it passes to the next level of your ArrayList and you call a notifyDataSetChanged() on your list.